# Python restrict newline characters for readlines()

Tags: python, python-2.7, readlines

I am trying to split a text which uses a mix of new line characters `LF`, `CRLF` and `NEL`. I need the best method to exclude `NEL` character out of the scene.

Is there an option to instruct `readlines()` to exlude NEL while splitting lines? I may be able to `read()` and go for matching only `LF` and `CRLF` split points on a loop.

Is there any better solution?

I open the file with `codecs.open()` to open `utf-8` text file.

And while using `readlines()`, it *does* split at NEL characters:

[image: session screenshot]

The file contents are:

```
"u'Line 1 \\x85 Line 1.1\\r\\nLine 2\\r\\nLine 3\\r\\n'"
```

Comment: What's a NEL character? More precisely - what is its ASCII/code-point value?

Comment: `NEL` (U+0085) is not a character `readlines()` supports, as far as I know.

Comment: @user5402: http://codepoints.net/U+0085

Comment: Why not just process character by character using read(1)?

Comment: @carl: Because it would likely be a lot slower.

Comment: A few relevant lines of your code could make answering this question much easier.

Comment: @msw I have already given a link to the screenshot to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file.readlines()` will only ever split on `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` depending on the OS and if universal newline support is enabled.

[U+0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)](http://codepoints.net/U+0085) is not recognised as a newline splitter in that context, and you don't need to do anything special to have `file.readlines()` ignore it.

Quoting the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> Python is usually built with universal newlines support; supplying `'U'` opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Macintosh convention `'\r'`, or the Windows convention `'\r\n'`. All of these external representations are seen as `'\n'` by the Python program. If Python is built without universal newlines support a mode with `'U'` is the same as normal text mode. Note that file objects so opened also have an attribute called newlines which has a value of None (if no newlines have yet been seen), `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\r\n'`, or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.

and the [*universal newlines* glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

> A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Windows convention `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention `'\r'`. See [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) and [PEP 3116](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/), as well as `str.splitlines()` for an additional use.

Unfortunately, `codecs.open()` *breaks* with this rule; the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamReader.readlines) vaguely alludes to the specific codec being asked:

> Line-endings are implemented using the codec’s decoder method and are included in the list entries if *keepends* is true.

Instead of `codecs.open()`, use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to open the file in the correct encoding, then process the lines one by one:

```
with io.open(filename, encoding=correct_encoding) as f:
    lines = f.open()
```

`io` is the new I/O infrastructure that replaces the Python 2 system entirely in Python 3. It handles just `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`:

```
>>> open('/tmp/test.txt', 'wb').write(u'Line 1 \x85 Line 1.1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n'.encode('utf8'))
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open('/tmp/test.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()
[u'Line 1 \x85', u' Line 1.1\r\n', u'Line 2\r\n', u'Line 3\r\n']
>>> import io
>>> io.open('/tmp/test.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()
[u'Line 1 \x85 Line 1.1\n', u'Line 2\n', u'Line 3\n']
```

The `codecs.open()` result is due to the code using [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) being used, which [has a documentation bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22232); when splitting a unicode string, it'll split on anything that the Unicode standard deems to be a line break (which is [quite a complex  issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7643)). The documentation for this method is falling short of explaining this; it claims to only split according to the Universal Newline rules.

Comment: I honour your answer which is informative.But, the problem still not solved. I do not want to remove NEL characters. I just want to exclude it while splitting lines.

Comment: @Gaudha: they are **not split on**. They don't need ignoring. If they are, you don't have NEL characters. Can you show us a `repr()` representation of your data?

Comment: @Gaudha: in other words, please supply (in your question) a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by which you demonstrate the problem and explain the expected outcome instead.

Comment: `"u'Line 1 \\x85 Line 1.1\\r\\nLine 2\\r\\nLine 3\\r\\n'"`

Comment: @Gaudha right, it appears that the file object produced by `codecs.open()` does split on NEL. You cannot configure that. Does `io.open()` do the same? If so, use regular `open()` and decode each line (`[line.decode('utf8') for line in open(filename)]`). I'll look into more options tomorrow.

Comment: @Gaudha: I now had time to suss this out properly. `codecs.open()` indeed splits on U+0085, and that behaviour is at best *very poorly* documented. Use `io.open()` instead, and I've linked you to the bug reports that are at the hart of this difference.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

f = [re.sub(' \\r ', '', str(line)) for line in open('file.csv', 'rb')]
```

Will create a list of strings that will ignore additional `\r` characters. Each element in the list will be a line from the file. I had a similar issue and this worked on my csv. You may need to change the regex expression in the `re.sub` section to fit your needs.

**NOTE:** This will get rid of the `\r` character and replace it with `''`. I was wanting to get rid of them, so it worked for me.